# Jquery boxslider is not working on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am fixing just a few minor issues and adding a few pictures and recipes to a friend's website http://mariorizzotti.com who a couple of years ago had it made by a webdesigner. Anyhow, I have been adding a few pictures and changing some of the css, the only problem I am having is getting the jquery bxslider to work on the homepage correctly. It is working on the media page but not on the homepage. The images that are being called are all in the correct folders. Any suggestions by looking at the source code? The only thing I have been able to come up with is that the click handler isn't being called in the homepage. I checked it in chrome's console but not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. There is a JavaScript error during page load on line 31 of `index.php`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tweet'
```

This prevents subsequent scripts from executing, so the slider initialization on line 87 doesn't run and the click handlers for changing slides aren't registered. Fixing the error should be as simple as including the `jquery.tweet.js` script on `index.php` as it is on `videos.php`.